# Minimum sum of two arrays choosing half of the elements in each

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Hello I am not a so called professional programmer. I have two arrays `a1` and `a2` of `integer`s with same *even length* `n`. I need to find the *minimum total sum* of elements in `a1` and `a2` by selecting one element for *each index* and *half* of the selected elements should reside in a1 and the rest is in a2.

**Example**:

```
 a1 = [36, 72];  
 a2 = [35, 61];
```

The result should be `97` since we should choose `36` from `a1` and `61` from `a2`. I think one solution would be choosing *all possible* `n/2` elements in `a1` and `a2` and computing their results. Can a *more efficient* solution be found ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: the usual approach is with one loop and checking if the index is even or odd. Two separate loops can be a tiny bit more efficient because no index check and branch misprediction, but more likely to make an off by one error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's represent arrays `a1` and `a2`

```
    a1 = [36, 72];  
    a2 = [35, 61];
```

in a different way: we combine i-th indexes and compute a `penalty = a2[i] - a1[i]`:

```
    a = [(36, 35; penalty = -1), (72, 61; penalty = -11)]
```

Here `penalty` is a price we have to pay when we choose `a2` value instead of `a1`. Let's sort by penalty

```
    a = [(72, 61; penalty = -11), (36, 35; penalty = -1)]
```

Now let's choose `n/2` items with the lowest penalties and take `a2` items; choose `n/2` items with highest penalties and take `a1` items:

```
    a = [(72, 61; penalty = -11), (36, 35; penalty = -1)]
         (72, 61; penalty = -11) - lowest,  take a2 item - 61
         (36, 35; penalty = -1)  - highest, take a1 item - 36
```

Time complexity is `O(n * log(n))` - sorting.

**C#** implementation:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[] a1 = new int[] { 36, 72 };
  int[] a2 = new int[] { 35, 61 };

  var result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, a1.Length)
    .Select(i => new {
      v1 = a1[i],
      v2 = a2[i],
    })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.v1 - item.v2)
    .Select((item, index) => index >= a1.Length / 2 
       ? item.v1 
       : item.v2)
    .Sum();

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  97
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful and clever.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing all possible n/2 elements and looking for the minimum will work, but will be very costly. In particular the runtime complexity will be O(n^n).

The basic idea is that you want to choose elements at index i with a high difference `|a1[i] - a2[i]|`. So here is a sketch of an algorithm:

1. Build a new array d where `d[i] = |a1[i] - a2[i]|`
2. Now take index `i` in descending order of `d`. So the index of the largest element in `d` first then the index of the second largest element in `d` and so on.
3. For each index `i` you get from step 2. take the smaller element of `a1[i]` and `a2[i]` and add it to your sum. You also will track how many elements you took from `a1` and how many from `a2`. If at one point you took `n/2` of either you fill up the sum with the remaining entries form the other array.

Example:

```
a1 = [11, 12, 13, 12]

a2 = [15, 2,  30, 14]

d  = [4 , 10, 17, 2]
```

So here first pick a1[2] (13) since d[2] is the largest element in d and a1[2] <  a2[2]. Next you pick a2[1] (2) since d[1] is the second largest element in d. Next you pick a1[0] (11) because of the same reasoning as before. Lastly, you realized that you already picked two elements from a1 thats why you add all remaining elements from a2 to your sum (14). The result is thus 13 + 2 + 11 + 14 = 40

When implemented efficiently this can run in O(n log n)